# GMT date string getting converted to UTC Date

Tags: ios, nsdate

[image]**

1. GET GMT DATE STRING

**

```
   func getGMTString(dateAsDate:NSDate) -> String
    {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"//this your string date format
        // dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        //        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
        let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateAsDate)

        return date
    }
```

1. OUTPUT
   startDate---2016-06-29 00:00:00 GMT+5:30 
   endDate----2016-06-30 03:57:39 GMT+5:30
2. NOW TRYING to get GMT Date object from output string

   ```
    func getGMTDate(string:String) -> NSDate {
       let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"//this your string date format
     // dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")!
     //  dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
       let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(string)


       return date!
   }
   ```

   PROBLEM:  OUTPUT DATE OBJECT *MESS*
   startDateOBJECT---2016-06-28 18:30:00 +0000 endDateOBJECT----2016-06-30 17:30:00 +0000
3. **Unable to figure what is going wrong**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your step 3. I looks like you're using NSLog or a Swift print to display the resulting date. That is ALWAYS done in UTC.

If you want to view your date in a different format, or with your local time zone, you need a second date formatter to convert the NSDate to an output date string.

Here's the flow:

```
input date string -> input date formatter -> NSDate

NSDate -> output date formatter -> display date in local time zone
```

Comment: Thank You @Duncan for reply, i am using print both time (OUTPUT startDate & OUTPUT DATE OBJECT).

Comment: & one more thing i will like to add, i need to pass date object instead printing it. so need to make sure the date format is GMT & as per local device.

Comment: An NSDate object does not have a format. It is a very thin wrapper around a timestamp. It does not contain ANY other state data. Formatting a date is the job of a date formatter and a calendar object.

Comment: Thanks, i figured out. I just interpreted incorrectly the logs.